# Is the new Feast mastery more impactful than Double Edged Sword?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was fixing up my mastery pages, and I stumbled upon the Feast mastery. At first, I ignored this mastery, as I felt that it was essentially useless.

[image]

Whereas Double Edged Sword, seems infinitely more useful and can have a large impact on the game, despite the increased damage taken.

[image]

In summary, is 20 health every 25 seconds actually useful on specific champions, or does dealing extra damage, but taking additional damage pose more of an impact on the the game?

Comment: Anecdotally, I have heard that Double Edged Sword is generally better on melee champions while Feast is generally better on ranged champions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Feast mastery equates to 4HP/5 which is great for lane sustain. I pick this up on marksmen 100% of the time myself. As well as mid laners who primarily want to sit back and farm the lane.

If you are playing anyone who relies more on lane kills than CS (such as assassin mids or carry top laners like Riven and Fiora), you will want to go for Double-edged Sword to increase your damage dealt.

Double-edged Sword obviously does work better on melee mids like Talon and Katarina, and top laners than it would for say Ahri or LeBlanc. So you may want to look up at your match-up (if in draft mode) and decide if Feast might be best for that game in particular.

Comment: I find feast to be better in almost all cases. The 2% bonus damage on a 1200 veigar ult is only 24 which IMO is not worth it.

Comment: Note that the Double-edged Sword mastery has been changed for ranged champions since this answer was posted.

Comment: The mastery is now further down the tree, and it's now "Deal 5% more, take 2.5% more." Masteries change every year, so it's expected that questions/answers on them will become outdated.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on what you want to play.

Consider you tr to burst someone doing 2% extra damage is nice and if you die after getting your burst out isnt to bad.

As a tank taking extra damage isn`t the best choice and having some extra sustain especially in the top sustained fights is great.

Personally i almost always go feast but its just preference.

Answer (score 1):

as adc you need double edged sword, because adc is all about positioning, and that extra damage you take wont change anything for you, because if you die instantly, you die instantly.

Comment: That being said, having more sustain during laning phase means you can stay in lane longer, which leads to more farm, which makes you stronger faster.